# Compiling Qt5 in FreeBSD console

Tags: qt, compiler-construction, freebsd

Is there is a way to build q5 projects under FreeBSD console? I have found only qt4 in ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Some effort](http://www.kdab.com/last-week-in-qt-development-week-17-2012/) has been made for that. The compiler requirement is GCC 4.6. There's also some [discussion](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/24009) about Qt5 and BSD on Qt Project website. They say the X11 version is compatible with BSD, but you must compile it from source.

Comment: Yes, with gcc 4.6+ everything compilied fine!